# Is it known if the ground state of an arbitrary electronic many-body problem has antisymmetric spatial part?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors, spin-statistics, ground-state

For ***non-interacting electrons***, Hund's rule (#1) says that the state with the highest total spin has the lowest total energy. For two independent electrons, it seems then that the electrons should be in a triplet configuration, i.e. that the spatial part be antisymmetric.

***In complete generality***: Is it true that the spatial part of the ground state of interacting electrons in an external potential is anti-/symmetric? If so, can you explain why, or provide a reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Fermions_and_bosons

Comment: @Wolphramjonny, sorry, I cannot see the relevance? I know the wave function should be antisymmetric, but I am only asking about the spatial part in my question.

Comment: ohhh I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

It is known that this is not a rule. One counterexample is enough, $H_2$. Molecules with an even number of electrons and nonzero electronic spin in the ground state are rare. $O_2$ is an exception. See however https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-molecule_magnet.

Comment: Thanks! Are you able to provide a reference for the $H_2$ ground state claim?

Comment: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=hydrogen+molecule+ground+state